# How to revert Windows 7's Windows Explorer to text-based address bar?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, address-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace Windows Explorer breadcrumbs with classic full path textbox?](https://superuser.com/questions/168007/how-to-replace-Windows-explorer-breadcrumbs-with-classic-full-path-textbox)

The button-based address bar in Windows Explorer in Windows 7 is annoying me. I want Windows Explorer to have the text-based address bar instead.

I know I can click the bar to reveal the path, but **how can I make the path be displayed by default?**

F0r N00bs: [image]

F0r h4xx0rz: [image]

Comment: You're not doing yourself any favors in trying to revert UI changes.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I disagree but I am not going to start an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures. I always find [the answer](https://superuser.com/questions/168007/how-to-replace-windows-explorer-breadcrumbs-with-classic-full-path-textbox) *after* posting, despite not finding it after a Google search and two SU site searches.

MS offers no native solution. One needs to use third-party hacks to accomplish this.