# Back slash in the windows explorer address bar

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, address-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace Windows Explorer breadcrumbs with classic full path textbox?](https://superuser.com/questions/168007/how-to-replace-windows-explorer-breadcrumbs-with-classic-full-path-textbox)

In windows explorer, the address bar shows the folders with forward arrows.
If I click the down arrow at the end of the address line I get the old indication with a back slash.

Now I prefer this method so I click this down arrow. But, if I click the 'search bar' the 'address bar' refers to the forward arrow version. This most frustrating. This also happens if I have two windows side by side.

My question, how can I retain the `C:\Program Files\Adobe\` version, possibly permanently.

Comment: Just for the record, you don’t have to click on the down arrow; just click anywhere to the right of the last right arrow.