# How do I make windows explorer display the file path instead of words such as "Documents" or "Desktop"

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-8.1

If you ever click something on the sidebar in windows explorer:

[image]

the top thing says the name of what whatever you clicked:

[image]

However if you actually navigate to the place by clicking through the files starting at "This PC" it displays the path:

[image]

How do I force the top bar to always show the direct path instead of just the word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment, that doesn't seem possible to display the full folder path where you would like it. However, there is a option to display the full path in the title bar, task bar, and frankly, everywhere else except where you want it.

If you are interested: Open 'Folder Options' > Navigate to 'View' > Look under 'Files and Folders' and check the 'Display the full path in the title bar' option.

In my opinion, it's pointless. It should at least display the full path where the path is displayed. Anyway, wish I could've been of more help.

Also, I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/168007/how-to-replace-windows-explorer-breadcrumbs-with-classic-full-path-textbox) question.

Additionally, a solution has been linked [here](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/02/win7-remove-windows-explorer.html)

Currently testing it, pretty cool, but not 100%. It is, however an executable. So it's required to run while you want the feature enabled. It doesn't require elevated rights. And it's available in 32-bit and 64-bit versions, testing the 64-bit version.

[Here's](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/02/win7-remove-windows-explorer.html) the link.

Comment: I know of that however I want it in the bar thingy... Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @chipperyman573 Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it later tonight and report back.

Comment: That software doesn't work on windows 8 just a heads up.

Comment: @chipperyman573 That's unfortunate, it must've been disabled in an update. I tested it on a system running Windows 8 Pro x64 without any installed updates.

Comment: ...It must've been disabled in one of the updates or something. I'll keep a heads-up for something that works. Do you need it for 32 or 64-bit? Also, would you be okay with a full Explorer replacement? Lastly, thanks for compacting my post, it's appreciated.

Comment: I need 64 bit, and I like windows explorer. However it's clear you tried and this will probably work for XP/7 users so I'll keep it marked as correct.

Comment: @chipperyman573 It's nice that it might work for them, but the linked post is perhaps better suited. There's no reason to accept my answer if it didn't help answer your question.

Comment: actually the full path registry setting works on everything except the "desktop" and other library type places that are not really real (created via registry shell magic).  Control Panel, Recycle Bin, Desktop, etc etc are affected, but normal folders seem to display full path title just fine.  At least on my 2012-R2 VM

Comment: I hope whatever marketing airhead or UX designer who thought this was a good idea loses their job and never gets another one.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a link to a "network location" pointing to Desktop, Documents, Downloads, or whatever you want.

**For example:**

In Windows Explorer, navigate to `\\Your-Actual-PC-Name\c$\Users\your-user-name\Desktop`.

Windows 7: Scroll the navigation pane all the way back up to the top. 
There should be a "Favorites" folder at the very top:

[image]

Right click on "Favorites" and select "Add current location to Favorites".
You can then modify the name and icon of the shortcut in the Properties menu.

Windows 10: Right click on "Quick Access" and select "Pin current folder to Quick access"

This does have the downside of the breadcrumbs showing

```
► Network ► Your-Actual-PC-Name ► c$ ► Users ► your-user-name ► Desktop
```

but it does allow for navigating up the tree.

You can also replace your PC name with `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, or create an entry in your hosts file to call it whatever you want.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, and I don't see a "Favorites" button or link in Windows Explorer.  Please clarify your answer.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SmuH5.png

Windows 7 has the Favorites menu shown by default in the navigation pane. Did you remove it?

Comment: I edited your answer to make it clear enough that dummies like me can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has been covered but my annoyance was that the Search bar to the right of the network path takes a lot of space and blocks you from seeing longer paths.

But here are two things.

First if you click on empty space to the right in the network path:
[where to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEWHF.png)

Then the path changes from the folders that you can click on to navigate directly to them to the full path with the backslashes:
[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd1Yy.png)

But my problem was with long paths and the Search field taking the space of the network path then I realized you can just left press and hold mouse button between the network path and search and you get a left-right slider image and can slide the search windows to the right to decrease its size which enlarges the network path field:
[slide field size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sax5a.png)

to this:
[resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V02Gw.png)

hope this is what you were looking for.